# JavaScript callbacks and events

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

For one of my lecture at university we are learning about callbacks, I half understand what they are but the question I have is where can you find the events for elements.

load in:

```
img1.addEventListener(’load’, function() {
// woo yey image loaded
});
```

yay in:

```
some_function("yay", function(value) {
console.log("callback called! " + value);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them in the [MDN Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: Is this the same for every browser or just Mozilla?

Comment: It depends on the Specification column. Those specified in DOM L3 are most likely to work on any browser, while HTML5 events will probably only work on modern browsers.

Comment: Also, [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Non-standard_events) the Mozilla/Firefox OS specific events.